# Vlookup find match

Tags: excel

I want to get with my ID the matching string, I am trying to accomplish that with a VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(L2;Tree_Matchingnode!A:B;1;0)
```

The Table that I am doing the Vlookup looks like this:

```
+----------------+------------------+
| Parent_TREE_ID | Parent_TREE_NAME |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 |                  |
|              2 |                  |
|              3 |                  |
+----------------+------------------+
```

The Matching tabel looks like this:

```
+-------------+----+
| Folder_PATH | ID |
+-------------+----+
| Path1       |  1 |
| Path3       |  9 |
| Path15      |  3 |
+-------------+----+
```

My result should be that the the ID's from the first table match the correct path coming from the second table

The result that I get is #N/A which is wrong and the L2 would be  Parent_TREE_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get columns on the right with `VLOOKUP` and not on the left. Rather use `INDEX-MATCH` as it is much more flexible:

Instead of:

```
=VLOOKUP(L2;Tree_Matchingnode!A:B;1;0)
```

Use something like:

```
=INDEX(Tree_Matchingnode!A:A,MATCH(L2,Tree_Matchingnode!B:B,0),1)
```

Comment: I would upvote if I could tnx allot for your help 100% correct